# Is there a way to add labels inside a plot for each point in R?

Tags: r, plot, label

I would like to add a label for each Year [2008-2017] for mean of Distance_m (Distance in meters) vs mean of RAI_CS (Relative Abundance Indices per Camera Station). I used `plot` and `ggplot` but have had no success.

I tried this code using `plot`.

`plot(tapply(MyData$RAI_CS, MyData$Year, mean)~tapply(MyData$Distance_m, MyData$Year, mean), MyData)`

I cannot get the `label=Year` to work. I come close with this code but cannot get the labels for each year to show, only data points of means, unhelpful as I don't know which year is which.

I tried this code in `ggplot`.

`ggplot(MyData, aes(x=mean(MyData$Disctance_m), y=mean(MyData$RAI_CS), label=MyData$Year))+ geom_point()`

I get this warning message for `ggplot`
Warning messages:

1: In mean.default(MyData$Disctance_m) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(MyData$Disctance_m) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: Removed 2938 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

However, my data is numeric despite this warning. I want the mean distance vs mean RAI and one data point for each year to be labelled with the year on the plot.

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible example, what your dataframe looks like ?

Comment: Could you add a sample of your data with `dput`? Avoid `$` in the `tidyverse` and also check that `Distance*` or `RAI*` is indeed numeric.

Answer (score 2):

Taking Iris dataset as an example, since dataset details are not provided please try to run below & understand, using geom_text to add labels to geom_point

```
data("iris")
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(label=Species))
```